# Where's my mistake applying Perron's Formula?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, contour-integration

I applied Perron's Formula to Riemann Zeta Function and got a weird result.
First, I started with a simple definition of Riemann Zeta Function,
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}$$
where $\Re(s)>1$. Applying Perron's Formula,
$$\sum_{n\leq x}'\frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz$$
for $c>0$. $\sum'$ means that the last term of the sum should be multiplied by 1/2 when $x$ is an integer. We can calculate the integral easily using Residue Theorem. We have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz=\zeta(s)+\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$$
since
$$\underset{z=0}{\mathrm{Res}}\ \zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}z\left(\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}\right)=\zeta(s)$$
and
$$\underset{z=-s+1}{\mathrm{Res}}\ \zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow1-s}(s+z-1)\left(\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}\right)=\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}.$$
Actually this is a weird result.
In fact, it is true that
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\zeta(s)+\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+O\left(x^{-s}\right)$$
but both side except the error term cannot be equal.

Comment: When you use residue theorem on $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, you should always be careful. I suggest truncation of integral and use residue theorem inside a finite region.

Comment: The residue theorem works for closed contours. You're trying to apply it to a vertical line; that's not always going to work. (What makes you sum the residues to the left of the line, instead of those to the right, for example?)

Comment: Thanks. Now I realized what was going wrong.

Comment: See this [second formula with the error terms](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_de_Perron).

Comment: To be specific, this line is false:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s+z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz=\zeta(s)+\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s},$$ because the contour integration has not been done correctly.